# Have I invoked correctly?

Tags: java, methods, invoke

I have been given a piece of code (the class QuestionTwo). 
I am asked to state the values of a, b, and c after method mQ2 is invoked on a newly created object of class Q2.

**My main.java file**

```
package openuniversity;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    QuestionTwo qt = new QuestionTwo();
    qt.mQ2();
  }
}
```

**My QuestionTwo.java class file:**

```
package openuniversity;

public class QuestionTwo
{
  int a;
  int b = 1;

  public void mQ2()
  {
    {
      int c;
      int a = 2;
      c = a;
    } 

    {
      int c;
      int a;
      c = 3;
      a = 4;
    }

    a++;

  }
}
```

I arrived at:

```
a: 1
b: 1
c: 3
```

**Note I can also select 'undefined' as an answer?
So would it be 1, 1, undefined as c does not exist outside of the codeblock?**

**The question:**

Study the following code and then select the options from the drop-down lists below that are correct about the values of a, b and c after the method mQ2 is invoked once on a newly created object of class Q2. Note that the answers you choose for a, b and c may or may not be different from each other.

```
public class Q2
{
    int a;
    int b = 1;

    public void mQ2()
    {
        {
            int c;
            int a = 2;
            c = a;
        }
        {
            int c;
            int a;
            c = 3;
            a = 4;

            System.out.println("c: " + c);  //correct place?  
        }
        a++;
    }
    System.out.println("a: " + a + "b: " + b);  // correct place?
}
```

Comment: How did you arrive at that? Have you thought about how you can verify/disprove your claim?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me. Note that there are both local and class variables here. The local variables effectively cease to exist when the function exits, so they don't really have a value IMO.

Comment: If you declare a variable in a block ( `{ ... }` ) it stops existing after that block is complete. Therefore, there are multiple distinct variables named `a` and `c`, and as Adrian said there is no `c` after `mQ2()` has run.

Comment: The question, IMO, is just made to trip me up and check I understand code blocks and local variables I think. I will edit my post to put the question exactly as I have it infront of me at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you first print out all the values using System.out.println() after calling mQ2, then step through the code in your mind to try to work out *why* the values are what they are. Remember that any variable declared is only visible within the scope (`{...}`s for simplicity), but these variables can have the same name as other variables so they might look like the same even if they're not.

I'd like to particularly point out that c does not exist outside that method.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thor, it's appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll restrict my answer to a couple of pointers.

1. You can verify your solution by printing out the variables after calling `mQ2()` (hint: you could use `System.println()` for that).
2. This is either a trick question or is partially ill-defined (hint: think about **which** `a`, `b` and especially `c` you're being asked about).

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I appreciate them. My confusion is where EXACTLY to put my System.out.println?

Would I put (a + b) just above the last brace? and (c) under where a=4?

Comment: You have to print them from your own Class (the variables haven't got public/private specified so they've defaulted to protected, meaning you'll have access as long as you're in the same package), or just make a separate toString() method in the question Class that prints a/b (which you can call from the last line of mQ2). You can only print c inside the mQ2 method, but I'm guessing that's part of the question - it has no value because it doesn't exist *after the execution of the method*.

Comment: Thanks aix, I appreciate you helping out!